# Mailchimp 2 for Magento 2 not sync users - permissions?

Tags: magento2, php, newsletter, mailchimp

I have upgraded my mailchimp extension from ebizmarts to mailchimp 2 for magento 2. And quess what? It stopped working.
1. The plugin is installed.
2. The api key returns follwing mailchimp list

```
Account Details 
Username: username
Total Subscribers: 10
Ecommerce Data uploaded to MailChimp
Total Customers: 0
Total Products: 0
Total Orders: 0
Total Carts: 0
Synced since
```

On my magento backend I have 98 newsletter subscribers. Right now it does not sync the users from magento newsletter module, and also, it is not adding new users when I enter the email through the website email field.

Is it possible to have some permission issues, and which would those folders be?

Or maybe I am missing some step?

Comment: Did you find a solution fro this ? if so can you share please?thanks